# What is the mechanism of folic acid deficiency and neural tube defects?

Tags: human-biology, development, embryology

I am having difficulty finding the mechanism by which folic acid reduces the risk of neural tube defects. I know that it does so, but what in particular actually occurs with folic acid deficiency to cause the neural tube defect? Is that completely unknown and merely a strong association, or is there a putative mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having difficulties finding the mechanism because it is as of yet unknown.

Now of course comes the hard part where I need to prove that statement. Often, it's just apparent by papers not saying anything about the mechanism, even though you'd expect then to include a brief section if it was known, for example [Folic acid supplementation for pregnant women and those planning pregnancy: 2015 update](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcph.616/full) or the various Cochrane reviews on the topic of how much folic acid supplementation is optimal, or the WHO and CDC documents on the topic

Here's a few relatively recent ones that state it outright:

[Folic Acid Supplementation and Pregnancy: More Than Just Neural Tube Defect Prevention](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3218540/), 2011

> The mechanism by which folic acid prevents structural anomalies in the fetus is not known, but may involve the regulation of homocysteine metabolism

[Folic acid supplementation in pregnancy and implications in health and disease](http://www.jbiomedsci.com/content/21/1/77), 2014

> as FA deficiency may be a risk factor for NTDs additional studies will be required to determine the mechanistic role of the FA pathway in the onset of neural tube defects

FA = Folic Acid, NTD = Neural Tube Defects

[Neural Tube Defects, Folic Acid and Methylation](http://www.mdpi.com/1660-4601/10/9/4352/htm), 2013

> To date, animal studies have not provided 
>   sufficient information to establish the metabolic and/or genomic mechanism(s) underlying human folic acid responsiveness in NTDs.

There are some putative mechanisms to do with folic acids effects on the [homocysteine metabolism](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2964004/) and [its effects on methylation](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19301298). I can't really tell how well-established those are yet, but maybe this can be a starting point for you.